# Is there a way to run WScript JScript interactively

Tags: javascript, jscript, wsh

Python can be run interactively so I was wondering if it is also possible to run WScript Javascript (Microsoft call it JScript) interactively.

I see I can run a script like this:
cscript hello.js

with contents:

```
WSH.Echo("Hello world");
WSH.Quit();
```

But I just want to do something like:

```
Echo("Hello world");
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Not without some kind of a wrapper, and even that would be pretty fugly.  You'd really be better off having the file open in an editor (not full screen) and having a shortcut to the `.js` file on the desktop.  Save your file, then double-click the icon to run it.  If you want to run under `wscript` instead of `cscript` -- look at the `cscript /?`.  It has directions to change the default script handler.

Comment: If you are open to an alternative JavaScript engine that runs on Windows, you may also look into Rhino, which has an REPL mode and quite powerful exposing Java. Failing that, you could write a JScript script that behaves like a console.